# K-Means Clustering variable results depending on sort order of data

Tags: clustering

I'm using PASWStatistics18 and K-Means clustering data that I'd previously clustered using an earlier version of SPSS... My problem is that I'm getting different cluster results depending on how the data file is sorted.  I can't remember this being an issue in the earlier versions of SPSS, but I can't repeat the same results, using the same data file, again!  Only by using the saved cluster centres can I get close to the original result.

Have others had similar isues?  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I don't know about PASWStatistics18 but it seems like either the initialisation of the first k centers is different for each run, or a mean is immediately updated after each datapoint (or some datapoints) assignation (like for the online k-means) .

Answer (score 3):

This is a well-known property of k-means. The initialization is usually **randomized**, so you might even get (and in fact, *intend* to get) different results for multiple runs. It is a common best practise with k-means to run it multiple times, and choose the one with the minimum average distances (or by some other internal metric).

`DBSCAN` is mostly order independent. Only for fringe points that could belong to two different clusters, the cluster assignment is not stable (unless you extend `DBSCAN` to support multi-assignments or use some other stable tie-braking rule).

In general, it actually is even a good idea to shuffle your dataset before doing any kind of analysis. Say your method fails completely, and returns the data set in its original order. If the data was sorted before, the output will look meaningful. So always shuffle your data.

Comment: You will not get a different results using the classical k-means where the means are computed only after each pass over the hole dataset, unless you initialise the first k centers differently for each run, or you update the mean immediately after each datapoint assignation (like for the online k-means)

Comment: Well, it is a best practise to try different random initializations, instead of using the first k objects (which, when the data set is sorted, are biased). And it very often even results in quite different output, so it is sensible to try different initializations (whether or not MacQueen proposed that) ...

Comment: You're right, and in this case, if you have all the dataset available beforehand, it will be much better to use a seeding procedure that allow to initialize centers with datapoints that are far from each other, rather than pure random initialization.

Answer (score 2):

Actually SPSS has acknowledged, going back at least to version 13 (ca. 2003) that cluster solutions will be affected by sort order.  This applies not only to K-means but to its other clustering algorithms as well.  You'll find this information in the Help files and possibly in the Tutorial.  When using cluster analysis in SPSS I always create a random number and sort by that first.

Comment: can you give link to current help file?

Comment: Hierarchical clustering doesn't depend on case order unless there are ties in the diatance matrix.